# Is it true that George Washington was Offered Kingship?

Tags: united-states, kingdom

I recently heard a rumor that George Washington was offered to become king of America, but refused instead wanting a Presidency; is this rumor true or is it just just that, a rumor?

Comment: There are always people with big mouths and bad ideas; there certainly was a discussion about how the President was to be addressed in official statements.  He rejected being called "Your Majesty", as he was not a king.  This may be the origin of the tale you have heard.  Instead he went with "Mr. President", a more democratic moniker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elaboration on my comment; the bad idea came from my distant cousin, John Adams!

[How ‘His Highness’ George Washington Became ‘Mr. President’](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/harlow-giles-unger/how-his-highness-presidents-day_b_4784011.html)

Comment: IIRC, Mrs Washington wanted  to be called "Lady Washington"  - but I'm a mere Brit, stepping on the hallowed ground of Republicanism!  *grin*

Comment: @thehonrose: a source would give your comment more meaning.

Comment: I can't now find where I read that she desired it, but according to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martha_Washington)  she *was* known as "Lady Washington".

Answer (score 1):

No, this is completely a myth.

There were many presidents prior to Washington, just not one that encompassed the entire United States. Some states had presidents that represented them during the revolutionary period (1774-1778) but prior to the formation of the  U.S. federal government.

The idea of a rejection sounds good to modern readers, but the idea of a king was never entertained by the U.S. forefathers. They had, much to their credit and patriotism, more sense than that.  The myth comes probably from correspondence with Lewis Nicola, at a much later date.  Some letters he wrote to Washington eludes to the idea, but does not state it or spell it out.

Comment: This would be improved with some source references.

Comment: I wouldn't say completely.  It wasn't a forgone conclusion that the American system wouldn't immediately degenerate into a monarchy.  Hence King George III's famous quote about Washington peacefully ceding power... "If he does that, he will be the greatest man in the world." [paraphrase]